# EAR deployment is failing with error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException on weblogic 12.1.3.0.0

Tags: java, java-8, weblogic, weblogic12c

When I try to deploy Dep.ear it is throwing below error:

```
     <Deployer> <BEA-149205> <Failed to initialize the application "Dep" due to error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at com.bea.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.bea.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassInfoImpl.<init>(ClassInfoImpl.java:41)
        at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassfinderClassInfos.polulateOneClassInfo(ClassfinderClassInfos.java:240)
        at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassfinderClassInfos.populateClassInfos(ClassfinderClassInfos.java:193)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace    
        Caused By: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at com.bea.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.bea.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassInfoImpl.<init>(ClassInfoImpl.java:41)
        at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassfinderClassInfos.polulateOneClassInfo(ClassfinderClassInfos.java:240)
        at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassfinderClassInfos.populateClassInfos(ClassfinderClassInfos.java:193)
```

Weblogic version: 12.1.3.0.0 & OpenJDK version "1.8.0_275".

Please help me with troubleshooting this issue. TIA!

Comment: At first, WebLogic server is not supported with OpenJDK. You should install and run your weblogic server instances with Oracle JDK.
Could you post the complete error message and the complete stack trace from the server log file. Thx

Comment: With Oracle JDK 1.8 also getting the same error:

Comment: Could you post the complete error message and the complete stack trace from the server log file. Thx

Answer (score 0):

That issue happens when you have a class compiled with a newer JDK version, in your case > 1.8

Probably one of your libraries inside Dep.ear has the culprit.
more details:
https://devwebcl.blogspot.com/2019/01/weblogic-log4j2-asm.html